# Having issues with loading annotation with strings, cannot convert from string to float

Tags: python

I was getting a `Value error: Cannot convert string to float` while loading my annotation file so I modified my code to this:

```
def floats_from_string(line):
    nums = []
    try:
        for num in line.split(" "):
            nums.append(float(num))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return nums

def load_annoataion(p):
    text_polys = []
    text_tags = []
    if not os.path.exists(p):
        return np.array(text_polys, dtype=np.float32)
    with open(p, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for line in reader:
            label = line[-1]

            line = [i.strip('\ufeff').strip('\xef\xbb\xbf') for i in line]
            new_line = floats_from_string(line)

            x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 = list(map(float, new_line[:8]))
            text_polys.append([[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], [x4, y4]])
            if label == '*' or label == '###':
                text_tags.append(True)
            else:
                text_tags.append(False)
        return np.array(text_polys, dtype=np.float32), np.array(text_tags, dtype=np.bool)
```

after updating the code i get this error now:

```
File "/Users/shwaitkumar/Downloads/EAST-master/icdar.py", line 46, in floats_from_string
    for num in line.split(" "):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

im not good with programming but I think I'm implementing my solution to convert string to float wrong. here is my annotation file that i need to load to model. please help so that my model can load it:

```
15.025299 79.619064 91.971375 27.37761 111.49409 87.36937 120.44259 144.5673 और
195.26416 345.93964 346.07916 195.40369 296.7271 296.54498 411.9508 412.13293 किस
544.8015 579.83813 541.4978 506.46115 42.720642 60.455795 136.19897 118.46382 दिन
275.59427 311.88095 302.1434 265.85672 134.48518 159.5067 173.62825 148.60674 रूप
30.469978 163.88913 164.9093 31.490135 182.98358 181.51782 274.3758 275.84155 इस
33.57235 184.95844 185.26584 33.879738 354.1837 353.62552 436.9943 437.55246 तरह
-2.6164436 45.761616 53.37768 4.9996223 155.51007 137.70114 158.39023 176.19916 साथ
343.8163 512.32336 512.94495 344.4379 134.2903 132.54332 192.49599 194.24297 एकाएक
337.52948 504.81384 505.13098 337.84662 241.95956 240.91986 291.94846 292.98816 रमानाथ
507.9361 555.0499 523.0799 475.96606 4.7673645 56.682793 85.69593 33.780502 गया
```

Comment: You're passing a `list` into `floats_from_string`.

Comment: split is on string only.. I think `type(line)` is list.. & split is not supporting to list, as it is already split-ed

Comment: @Linny @Harsha how can i convert string to float if i load a list? i just need to get all that data from annotation file but if keep getting error `ValueError: cannot convert string to float` as there might be some hidden space in my annotation file. can u guys help me implement my function properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a `List` as an argument for `floats_from_string`, then treating it like a string. `.split` is a string method, not a `List` method. You can keep this behavior, but just change the for loop:

```
def floats_from_string(numbers):
    nums = []
    try:
        for num in numbers:
            nums.append(float(num))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return nums
```

Why are you mapping the all the values to a float when the function already does it? I would change your code to something like this:

```
...
nums = floats_from_string(line)
text_polys.append([
    [nums[0], nums[1]], [nums[2], nums[3]], [nums[4], nums[5]], [nums[6], nums[7]]
])
...
```

Comment: i get this error now: `File "/Users/shwaitkumar/Downloads/EAST-master/icdar.py", line 71, in load_annoataion
    x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 = list(map(float, new_line[:8]))
1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 = list(map(float, new_line[:8]))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 8, got 0)`

Comment: Now an index out of range error has occurred. I tried to fix it myself by looking on internet but it won't work. here's the error description: `File "/Users/shwaitkumar/Downloads/EAST-master/icdar.py", line 73, in load_annoataion
    [nums[0], nums[1]], [nums[2], nums[3]], [nums[4], nums[5]], [nums[6], nums[7]]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Something is wrong with how you're parsing the values in the file then, because everything works on my end.